# Java Jface Table new row with autofocus

Tags: java, focus, swt, jface, tableviewer

My jface table has a rightclick listener for adding new rows.
When i do this i can autoselect the new empty row but i want automatically be able to write in the new row without clicking any keys or mousebuttons.

Im using the vogella tutorial which is using the editable class.

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html